# Firebase onMessageOpenedApp is Not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-web

I have 2 questions:

1- I have been trying to integrate push notifications with my Flutter web project, onMessage is working fine, but the method onMessageOpenedApp is not triggered neither getInitialMessage().
Its working fine on android but not on web.

2- Is it enough to call message.getToken('vapidKey:') or I have to do something more?

my main.dart:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
launch(message.data['url']);
await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
_setupLogging();

await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
runApp(
  EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: [Locale('en')],
      path: 'assets/translations',
      assetLoader: CodegenLoader(),
      fallbackLocale: Locale('en'),
      child: MyApp()),
);
await SharedPreferencesManager.instance.initialize();
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
await messaging.requestPermission(
  alert: true,
  announcement: false,
  badge: true,
  carPlay: false,
  criticalAlert: false,
  provisional: false,
  sound: true,
);

await messaging.getToken(
    vapidKey:
        'my key');
}
```

my homepage:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future setupInteractedMessage() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage? message) {
      if (message != null) {
        _handleMessage(message);
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                _handleMessage(message);
              },
              child: AlertDialog(
                title: Text(message.notification!.title!),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [Text(message.notification!.body!)],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          });
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage);
  }

  void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.data['type'] == 'NewOrder') {
      AutoRouter.of(context).pushNamed('/order_list');
    }
    if (message.data['type'] == 'UpdateOrder') {
      AutoRouter.of(context).pushNamed('/order_details/${message.data['id']}');
    }
    if (message.data['type'] == 'NewOrderTab') {
      AutoRouter.of(context).pushNamed('/table_order/${message.data['id']}');
    }
    if (message.data['type'] == 'UpdateOrderTab') {
      AutoRouter.of(context).pushNamed('/table_order/${message.data['id']}');
    }
    if (message.data['type'] == 'NewTable') {
      AutoRouter.of(context).pushNamed('/table_list');
    }
    if (message.data['type'] == 'UpdateTable') {
      AutoRouter.of(context).pushNamed('/table_list');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (!RestaurantBloc.instance.branch!.hasValue) {
      RestaurantBloc.instance.getBranch(id: widget.id);
    }
    SignalRService signalRService = SignalRService();
    signalRService.init();
    setupInteractedMessage();

    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: @DueabeS have you found this solution

Comment: Have you found the solution. I am experiencing the exact issue too. I have realised that sending a test message from firebase works but the notification sent from cloud functions doesn't.

Comment: After struggling so much I saw this in the Firebase docs: 
"Unfortunately we haven't yet been able to establish a proper way of communicating with the Service Worker and Flutter applications. Right now, all web background code must be executed in the JavaScript Service Worker file."

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem to return the token
like this :

```
    await messaging.getToken(
    vapidKey:
        'my key').then((value) => value);
}
```

Comment: sorry my first time commenting in stack overflow English is my second language so I just said it but this is the solution that worked for me :D, sorry for the misunderstanding